# Netlogo comparing list of global variables to numbers

Tags: list, global, netlogo

I apologise in advance for how simple the answer probably is to this question, I am very new to netlogo and very out of my depth.

I am trying to read a water-temperature from a file and consequently get my turtles to die/breed depending on the temperature. I have got the file to read finally, and set water-temperature as a global variable, however I am now stuck on the comparison part. It won't let me compare the variable to a number because I think the variable is a list. The following error message comes up;

```
The > operator can only be used on two numbers, two strings, or two agents of the same type, but not on a list and a number.
error while turtle 7 running >
  called by procedure REPRODUCE
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'go'
```

Code is below;

```
globals [ year 
  month 
water-temperature ]
extensions [ csv ] 


to setup
  ca
  load-data
  create-turtles 50
  [ set size 1
    set color red
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [ move
    reproduce ] 
  run-temperature 
end

to load-data
  file-close-all
    file-open "C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Documents\\Summer research project\\test3.csv"
end 

to run-temperature
    file-close-all
    file-open "C:\\Users\\Hannah\\Documents\\Summer research project\\test3.csv"
   while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    set water-temperature csv:from-row file-read-line 
  tick ] 
  file-close 
end 

to move
 rt random 50
  lt random 50
  fd 1
end

to reproduce
  if water-temperature > 35 [ die ]
  if water-temperature > 30 and water-temperature < 34 [ hatch 1 rt random-float 360 fd 1 ] 
  if water-temperature > 25 and water-temperature < 29 [ hatch 2 rt random-float 360 fd 1 ]
  if water-temperature > 20 and water-temperature < 24 [ hatch 3 rt random-float 360 fd 1 ]
end
```

I would be so grateful for any help!

Thanks :)

Hannah

Answer (score 2):

welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please provide an example of the first few lines of your "test3.csv" file? That will help get your question sorted- if you have a header or multiple columns that could be causing your problems- multiple columns might be getting read in as a list. As well, I think you want `file-read` instead of `file-read-line`.

A few other things- your `load-data` procedure is unnecessary as far as I can tell (you only need the loading to occur in `run-temperature`).

More importantly, your code right now says something like: *"All turtles, move and reproduce. Now, read the **whole** temperature file line by line."* The problem is that your `while` statement is saying "until you have yet reached the end of the file, read a line, tick, and move to the next one." Additionally, your model will `tick` once per line, without the turtles ever doing anything- it probably is simpler to just have your `tick` at the very end of your `go` procedure. It is likely better to avoid the use of `while` in your `go` procedure in this scenario, as it will loop until the `while` condition is satisfied.

It might be easier to just read your whole `test.csv` and store it in a variable for easier access- here is one example. Using this setup:

```
globals [ 
  water-temperature
  water-temperature-list
]

to setup
  ca
  crt 50 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
```

First, tell Netlogo water-temperature-list is a list using set and []. Then, do the same file close/open as before to prep your file for reading. Then, use a similar `while` loop to read your temperatures into `water-temperature-list`, using `lput`:

```
  set water-temperature-list []

  file-close-all
  file-open "test3.csv"
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    set water-temperature-list lput file-read water-temperature-list
  ]
  file-close-all
  reset-ticks
end
```

Now your model more simply access those values, since they are stored in a model variable directly. You can easily use the `ticks` value with `item` as an index for that list- for example, on tick 0 the first element in the list will be accessed, on tick 1 the second element, and so on. For example:

```
to go 
  set water-temperature item ticks water-temperature-list

  ask turtles [
    if water-temperature > 30 [
      die
    ]
    if water-temperature <= 30 [
     rt random 60 
     fd 1
    ]
  ] 
  tick
end
```

Note that with this setup once you get to the end of your temperatures, there will be an error telling you that Netlogo can't find the next list element- you'll have to put a stop condition somewhere to prevent that.

I know that is an alternative to your approach but I hope that it's helpful. For another similar but more complicated example, check out this [model by Uri Wilensky](http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/2312#model_tabs_browse_procedures).